# Confusion regarding magnetic moment

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Is it possible to have a magnetic configuration without a north and a south pole?

My school textbook says that it is possible, as in the case of toroid and a wire carrying current. Now, the explanation given suggests that this type of case is possible if and only if a configuration has a net zero magnetic moment, as in the above case, but not for a bag magnet or a solenoid. However, I don't understand this justification, like how the di-polarity is related to the magnetic moment. Is there a mathematical interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if you have two dipoles that are right next to each other pointing in opposite directions.  Such a configuration has no dipole moment, and at long range the field is a "quadruple" field.  That's the next term in the multipole expansion.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the expression of the magnetic field at a large distance, and agree with you. However my question was how can we justify the existence of such 'non polar' magnetic field through the scope of magnetic moments alone.

Comment: I mean, the north and south poles are a fiction anyhow. Magnetic moments are in a sense defined by the asymptotic fields that are produced by a given distribution. Magnetic field lines emerge as closed loops because $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0$, so I guess any current density / field that satisfies $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{J}$ and forms closed B-field lines is perfectly legal in magnetostatics.